# PHP spl_autoload_register не работает

Tags: php, nginx, php7

Добрый день. Ради самообучения решил написать свой фреймворк, столкнулся со следующей проблемой

Есть такая конструкция

```
$route = new Route();
    $currentController = $route->getCurrentRoute();

    spl_autoload_register(function () use ($currentController) {
        $controllerFileName = __DIR__ . '/../App/Controllers/' . $currentController['controller'].'Controller' . '.php';
        if(file_exists($controllerFileName)) {
            include $controllerFileName;
        }
    });

    $controllerName = $currentController['controller'].'Controller';
    $controller = new $controllerName;
```

обращаюсь в браузере на корень сайта.
Должен запустится DefaultController.
Однако в ответ ошибка:

> Class 'DefaultController' not found in Core.php(23): Core\Core->activeController()

код самого контроллера

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use \Core\View;
use \Core\Controller;

/**
 * Class Default
 * @package App\Controllers
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html');
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В `$currentController['controller']` что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При инстанциации объекта из строки, строка должна содержать полный namespace класса:

```
 $ctrl = 'Default';
 $controllerName= "App\\Controllers\\{$ctrl}Controller";
 $controller = new $controllerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости у вас не правильно ищется путь к файлу, проверьте что внутри переменной `$controllerFileName`:

```
$controllerFileName = __DIR__ . '/../App/Controllers/' . $currentController['controller'].'Controller' . '.php';
```

Comment: > /var/www/test/Core/../App/Controllers/DefaultController.php

Вот такая строка

Comment: путь верный к файлу?

Comment: да, проверил.
file_exists($controllerFileName) возвращает true

Comment: Если прописать ститически include '/var/www/test/Core/../App/Controllers/DefaultController.php'; отработает код? и потом проверить если не отработает: include '../App/Controllers/DefaultController.php';

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Попробуйте сделать проще. Определите по дефолту путь к вашим файлам. И будет что-то вроде:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
$path = "Classes";
if(strpos($class, "Controller") > 0) {
    $path = "Controllers";
} else if (strpos($class,"Model") > 0) {
    $path = "Models";
}
$classFile = "../$path/$class.php";
file_exists($classFile) ? require_once ("../$path/$class.php") : die("Class not found!");   
});
```

Надеюсь поможет=)